# C# - creating a class whose constructor takes generic param results in casting exception

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have `IInfo` and its generic version:

```
public interface IInfo
{
    IInput Input { get; }
}

public interface IInfo<T> : IInfo where T : IInput
{
    new T Input { get; }
}
```

Class implementation:

```
public class Info : IInfo<IInput>
{
    public IInput Input { get; }    

    public Info (IInput input) {}
}
```

Factory to create IOutput from IInput:

```
public class GenericFactory<TInput, TOutput> where TInput : IInput where TOutput : IOutput
{
    public IOutput Create(IInfo info)
    {
        ConstructorInfo cInfo = typeof(TOutput).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IInfo<TInput>) });
        object output = cInfo.Invoke(new object[] {cInfo});
    }
}
```

To test the above code:

```
public class TestInput : IInput 
{       
}

public abstract class AbstractOutput<TInput> : IOutput where TInput : IInput
{       
}

public class TestOutput: AbstractOutput<TestInput>
{
    public TestOutput(IInfo<TestInput> info)
    {

    }       
}

public void Test()
{
    IInput input = new TestInput();
    IInfo info = new Info(input);

    var factory = new GenericFactory<TestInput, TestOutput>();
    IOutput output = factory.Create(info);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Object of type 'Info' cannot be converted to type'Info<TestInput>'.
```

Side note: I'm open to any suggestions to simplify/re-write the code in a different way.

Comment: We don't see the definition of _factory.

Comment: Should be var factory = new GenericFactory<TestInput, TestOutput>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public TestOutput(IInfo<TestInput> info)
{

}
```

Is expecting an `IInfo<TestInput>` *explicitly*. However, you're trying to call it with `IInfo<IInput>` (which is what `Info` is designed to be).

To make it clear, you could also write:

```
IInput input = new OtherInput();
IInfo info = new Info(input);

var factory = new GenericFactory<TestInput, TestOutput>();
IOutput output = factory.Create(info);
```

And now you've provided `IInfo<OtherInput>` to something expecting `IInfo<TestInput>`

You would need to make `IInfo<T>` *contravariant* to allow it to be cast, for example:

```
public interface IInfo<in T> : IInfo 
    where T : IInput
{
    //new T Input { get; }
}
```

But note that it's illegal to return `T` when with a contravariant interface. The alternative is to make `Info` generic, and change `Create` to accept `IInfo<TInput>`. That latter gives you the benefit of a compile-time error when trying to pass `IInfo<OtherInput>` to `Create()`, rather than a run-time error